# PHP proper login after hash

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

When I search for "php proper login", all I find is how to properly hash a password. However, I remember reading that the following code is wrong because you can just add ?loggedIn=True to the URL. So what is the proper way to do this?

```
if($hash == $hashFromDatabase){
    $loggedIn = True;
}

Then change the page accordingly to the value of $loggedIn.
```

Comment: You're reading obsolete warnings that deal with PHP installs that have `register_globals` turned on. Any recent PHP build has that turned off. If you are on a host that has a register_globals-enabled PHP, then I suggest you nuke that host and switch to something less stupid.

Comment: Just initialize the variable like `$loggedIn = false;` before checking the login state. Initializing variables is always a good habit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?loggedIn=True` would only work if you have `register_globals` enabled.  Check your ini settings (I *really* hope you don't).

You can also use `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = True`, or even `$_SESSION['user'] = $username` so that they remain logged in for multiple requests.

Comment: Luckily, it wasn't enabled. If it's as bad as you suggest, I fell bad for the guy who wrote the article.